# Processes behind statistical distribution laws: a compendium?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, references, modeling, poisson-distribution

The simple processes that "explain" the binomial, Gaussian or Poisson distribution are relatively well-known. [Johnson or shot noises may be known in restricted area of science](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1306/15892). Sometimes, a distribution obtains novel explanations, like the Tracy-Widom law ([Mysterious Statistical Law May Finally Have an Explanation](https://www.wired.com/2014/10/tracy-widom-mysterious-statistical-law/)). In [A Note on the Physical Meaning of the Weibull Distribution](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TR.1975.5215348), M. Malik, a physical meaning is described, despite that:

> This is with reference to one aspect of [Giorski's [1] Note that the > Weibull distribution has no physical meaning](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TR.1968.5216949). **Well, it has.**

Is there a book, or a comprehensive source that references the natural or physical  processes that drive a large number  of statistical  distribution laws, behind the generic parametric formulae?

Such a knowledge could improve the use of statistical laws in different contexts, taking into accounts the physics of the measurement, or the nature of the process.

For the record, two references where (imho) the processes behind the distribution are not so detailed:

- Statistical Distributions, Catherine Forbes *et al.*
- [Distribution  hand-book](http://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/textfiles/DistributionsHandbook.pdf), C. Walck

Comment: Johnson & Kotz is the distribution bible.  There will never be a truly comprehensive book of applications, in the sense you describe, because it would have to reference *every* phenomenon ever studied by means of a statistical law.

Comment: @whuber I may have to rephrase sometimes then: I am looking for the rationale driving laws (eg how counting under some assumptions leads to Poisson), disregarding specific applications, unless an application is very specific to a given law

Comment: Many distribution laws--probably all of them--arise in myriad ways in myriad settings.  Johnson & Kotz don't even attempt to document all the origins or motivations for distributions; they are content to describe just a few.